# Each epoch returns 0s for train_loss, valid_loss and error rate

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, fast-ai

I’m trying to run 10 epochs on the Food-101 dataset using ResNet50 and so far this is my output:

```
epoch   train_loss  valid_loss  error_rate  time
0   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    21:05
1   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    20:16
2   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    20:17
```

Why could this be the case?

This is my code:

```
from fastai import *
from fastai.vision import *
from pathlib import Path
from numba import vectorize
from subprocess import call, run
import os, git, glob, shutil

train_image_path = Path('images/train/')
test_image_path = Path('images/test/')
path = Path('../Food-101')

food_names = get_image_files(train_image_path)
file_parse = r'/([^/]+)_\d+\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$'

data = ImageDataBunch.from_folder(train_image_path, test_image_path, valid_pct=0.2, ds_tfms=get_transforms(), size=224)
data.normalize(imagenet_stats)

learn = cnn_learner(data, models.resnet50, metrics=error_rate)
learn.fit_one_cycle(10)
```

Comment: Doesn't `fit_one_cycle` take a learning rate parameter? Maybe this isn't the problem but i would give it a check

Comment: @umbreon29 it takes the # of epochs